# How to download an mp4 video from a blob url or m3u8?

Tags: url, video, browser, blob, m3u8

Researching this question leads one to downloading an m3u8 from a blob URL and then using software (i.e. [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/) or  i.e. VLC media player) to download an mp4 from the m3u8.

Was able to get an m3u8 from a blob URL (using Chrome *Inspect*) but when trying to download an mp4 video from it we only ever see "conversion failed". So, how to download a video from a blob URL or a blobs m3u8?

blob:
[blob:https://vidlink.org/daae80e0-9302-4da5-b824-34c78f9ecb94](http://blob:https://vidlink.org/daae80e0-9302-4da5-b824-34c78f9ecb94)

m3u8(s):
1:https://p2p.vidlink.org/pl/amaster/5a4d5fb5582fe1c617ed477901c04747/5a4d5fb5582fe1c617ed477901c04747.playlist.m3u8

2:https://vidlink.org/pl/gmaster/6f7fc53f-278e-4f1b-8c46-8c005a884f5e.m3u8